# Can the other external JavaScript content be automatically used?

Tags: support, javascript

When browsing a Stack Exchange site and encountering a message like

> ... Stack Exchange requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load. Retry using another source.

because of [GFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall), is there a way to make it automatically use the other source until explicitly changing that?

Comment: When clicking that link, it sets a cookie that results in the site using the other source on future page loads. Is the problem that the cookie isn't saved or keeps expiring for you?

Comment: I don't know which

Comment: If it's the former, it will not work on each and every page load. If it's the latter, it will work for some time but then stop.

Comment: probably the latter.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog what is "the other external javascript content"?