# Why am I stuck at entering a chat room?

Tags: support, chat

When I try to join a chat room in a web browser on a laptop running Linux, it is sometimes (and now often, or almost always) stuck with message "Loading [chatroom name]. Just a second". I was wondering what the possible causes of the problem are. For example, am I opening too many tabs in a browser? Can government censorship ([GFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall)) block me from entering a chatroom?

The console of the Chrome browser says, when loading https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat and getting stuck,

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
dev-chat:10          GET https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
master-chat.js?v=8e20450acb97:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jQuery.cookie (master-chat.js?v=8e20450acb97:4:13684)
    at master-chat.js?v=8e20450acb97:4:13692
jQuery.cookie @ master-chat.js?v=8e20450acb97:4
(anonymous) @ master-chat.js?v=8e20450acb97:4
dev-chat:156 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at dev-chat:156:13
(anonymous) @ dev-chat:156
dev-chat:1 Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at bindBRAINNotesEvents (chrome-extension://emajnoacacifjgmkkmheackniabamonm/content_script.js:1:2054)
    at chrome-extension://emajnoacacifjgmkkmheackniabamonm/content_script.js:1:8329
```

Note that I managed to connect to the chat room once last week under GFW, and am not sure why.

Comment: I'm going to assume its a SE chat room. What web browser and linux distro? from the mention of the GFW - are you in china? Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is stuck at loading due to jQuery not being fetched.  It is a known issue when you have third parties (Corporate IT, Governments, some ISPs, VPN providers, Anti-Virus, etc) with different interests take care of your internet connection.

Comment: @rene Thanks. I got it connected once last week though

Comment: @JourneymanGeek how shall I do for answering "Are there any errors in the browser console?"

Comment: Press the F12 key to open Developer Tools and switch to the Console tab, then refresh the page.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Thanks. See my update.

Comment: Like I already said before and you forgot, the Firewall blocks the JS hosted on Google. Without this JS, features don't work, all of them. The main Q&A sites of SE have fallback to alternative host, however all the rest don't have hence you can't use them. This includes se.com, chat, and Area51.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars did you mean to reply to my comment under an earlier post https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386600/can-the-other-external-javascript-content-be-automatically-used#comment1289870_386600? So it is not the JS scripts but where they are hosted matters, correct? Are the JS scripts only JQuery?

Comment: JS is used anywhere and everywhere, by all sites. That is what make the site interactive and not just static pages. When the JS is blocked, the sites can't function properly. Sorry but can't explain it any better. I believe many people use VPN to bypass the Firewall, you might try doing the same then you can use SE without any problems.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars can the problem be solved by hosting the JS scripts somewhere else?

Comment: Of course, and SE already doing it **on the main Q&A sites**. But like I was trying to explain, without any luck, chat, se.com and Area51 are not main Q&A sites, having different, old, and less/unmaintained codebase, so they can't make changes there. The JS required to operate the chat is hosted on Google, and it won't be changed.